# session.cookie_secure does not set the secure cookie attribute

Tags: php, security, cookies, attributes

I've set session.cookie_secure to 1/true in php.ini and running the following code behind apache or php-fpm+nginx server --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

After restarting php-fpm/apache, the 'secure' attribute does not appear in the Set-Cookie header. Checked using wget and firefox (developer tools > toggle tools > network)

```
echo session_get_cookie_params()[secure];
```

returns 1.
Forcing HTTPS CGI parameter to on/off doesn't make a difference. This change was verified using --

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
```

This give the same result in RHEL/CentOS/EL 6 (PHP 5.3.3), RHEL/CentOS/EL 7 (PHP 5.4) and Gentoo (PHP 5.6.29)

Answer (score 0):

[session.cookie_secure](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) configures the secure flag *only for cookies sent by PHP's session extension*; i.e. `Set-Cookie` headers triggered by `session_start()`, `session_regenerate_id()` calls.

It does not affect `setcookie()` or `setrawcookie()` (nor anything else in PHP that may send cookies to the client) - these functions have their own `$secure` parameter for that purpose.